# Switching out gpu's

Tags: windows-10, gpu

I have a desktop with a GTX 970 in it and i am running windows 10.  I am not getting the FPS that I was promised with it and I am wanting to switch it out for a GTX 1070 instead. Would my pc work if I just took out my 970 and put in the 1070 without changing anything else?

Comment: Probably?  It shouldn't hurt anything to try.  Windows might want you to reinstall your video driver.  As with everything, having a good backup of your system, or at least your data is important.

Comment: would it then be easier to just go back to windows 8, put the 1070 in, then download windows 10?

Comment: I can't imagine how that would make anything easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using my custom PC for years now. I started with the 750 ti and slowly moved up. I have changed RAM, my Motherboard, my Secondary HDD to a SSD. Never had any problems. Just pluck out the 970, insert the 1070, finish up the wiring and you are good to go. Downgrading your PC will only make life harder for you.

Comment: thanks a lot! My friends was telling me since I installed Windows 10 when I had my 970 that it wouldn't work with the 1070 because of how Windows 10 handles their piracy